# How to validate any date format pattern itself in Java

Tags: java, validation, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I just could not find any way to check if the provided pattern is valid or not before validating any date.

For example

```
String datePattern = "blablabla";
```

How can we validate if it's a valid pattern to create an object SimpleDateFormat or any other dateFormat.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat-java.lang.String-):

```
IllegalArgumentException - if the given pattern is invalid
```

In other words, catch the exception. If it's caught, it is an invalid pattern:

```
try {
    new SimpleDateFormat("invalid");
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // invalid pattern
}
```

Comment: @IswantoSan: In what way? (That comment is too vague to be helpful.)

Comment: Then it's probably not illegal? What is the pattern?

Comment: @IswantoSan: Well, that means the pattern is considered valid under Java 6. I find that surprising, and it doesn't mean it's a *useful* pattern, but it's valid...